# Putting column value in a variable depending on max value for another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

**Data**

```
structure(list(fold = 1:10, .metric = c("roc_auc", "roc_auc", 
"roc_auc", "roc_auc", "roc_auc", "roc_auc", "roc_auc", "roc_auc", 
"roc_auc", "roc_auc"), .estimator = c("binary", "binary", "binary", 
"binary", "binary", "binary", "binary", "binary", "binary", "binary"
), .estimate = c(0.747, 0.874, 0.764, 0.723, 0.73, 0.703, 0.789, 
0.812, 0.81, 0.799)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

```
fold .metric  .estimator .estimate
1    roc_auc  binary     .747
2    roc_auc  binary     .874
3    roc_auc  binary     .764
4    roc_auc  binary     .723
5    roc_auc  binary     .730
6    roc_auc  binary     .703
7    roc_auc  binary     .789
8    roc_auc  binary     .812
9    roc_auc  binary     .810
10   roc_auc  binary     .799
```

I have this dataframe I want to put the fold in a variabble where the estimate is the largest? How exactly can I do this?

So for this example, I would want to put `2` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of variable `fold` for all cases for which `estimate` is highest. But that would return multiple values if you have several lines reaching the same maximal value.

```
df$fold[df$estimate==max(df$estimate)]
```

If you only want one value, even if there are two maximal estimates, you can use:

```
df$fold[df$estimate==max(df$estimate)][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

may also work

```
df.1 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    my.max = max(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE))
```